# Fastest way to identify rows containing strings

Tags: r

I have a data frame of strings, with dimensions 30 columns by 5 million rows. I would like to identify rows containing any of a predefined list of strings. Is there any faster way to do it than my apply() + any() approach below?

Here is a reproducible example. Note that the strings in this example are random numbers, but in my application they are actual strings.

```
m <- 5E6
n <- 30

# Generate a matrix with random strings
A <- as.data.frame( matrix(sprintf('%.2f', sample.int(1000,m*n, replace=T)), nrow=m, ncol=n), stringsAsFactors=F)

# Generate a list of strings I want to find
search_strings <- sprintf('%.2f', sample.int(1000,30, replace=T))

#Which rows contain any of those strings?
system.time(findRows <- apply(A, 1, function (r) any ( r %in% search_strings)))
```

---

Dramatic improvement using answers below:

```
# Original
R> system.time(findRows <- apply(A, 1, function (r) any ( r %in% search_strings)))
   user  system elapsed
 33.439   2.748  36.739

# @Ronak's answers
R> system.time(findRows <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(A, `%in%`, search_strings)))
system.time(findRows <- rowSums(sapply(A, `%in%`, search_strings)) > 0)
   user  system elapsed
  5.225   0.790   6.252

R> system.time(findRows <- rowSums(sapply(A, `%in%`, search_strings)) > 0)
   user  system elapsed
  5.426   1.153   6.715

# @Ian's answer
R> system.time(A[A[,lapply(.SD,function(x){x %chin% search_strings})][,rowSums(.SD) > 0],])
   user  system elapsed
  4.542   0.445   5.033
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` especially on big dataframes is slower.

Try these two alternative approaches in base R using `lapply` and `sapply` :

```
#lapply
findRows <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(A, `%in%`, search_strings))
#sapply
findRows <- rowSums(sapply(A, `%in%`, search_strings)) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `data.table`?

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)
findRows <- A[,lapply(.SD,function(x){x %chin% search_strings})][,rowSums(.SD) > 0]
```